# Access multiple system using single user credential in orangehrm

Tags: orangehrm

> how to connect more than one system authentication using single credential in orangehrm?
>
> I have add one user in system1 and that user will be automatic added into system2 using orangehrm. How I do that? Please Reply me if any one know answer about it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to two OrangeHRM systems. If you can sync the `ohrm_user` table in both systems, you can achieve this.

You can write an external script/app which syncs the two tables periodically (eg: every 5 minutes).